Explanation to layman on the effect of zero-ing in frequency domain
Unable to understand the answer to Why is it a bad idea to filter by zeroing out FFT bins?. Please elaborate and explain in layman's term what the answer is saying. Also by any chance is it related to What is Frequency Resolution?

Zeroing bins in the frequency domain is the same as multiplying by a rectangular window in the frequency domain. Multiplying by a window in the frequency domain is the same as circular convolution by the transform of that window in the time domain. The  transform of a rectangular window is the Sinc function ($\sin(\omega t)/\omega t$).  Note that the Sinc function has lots of large ripples and ripples that extend the full width of time domain aperture.  If a time-domain filter that can output all those ripples (ringing) is a "bad idea", then so is zeroing bins.
These ripples will be largest for any spectral content that is "between bins" or non-integer-periodic in the FFT aperture width. So if your original FFT input data is a window on any data that is somewhat non-periodic in that window (e.g. most non-synchronously sampled "real world" signals), then those particular artifacts will be produced by zero-ing bins.


Well, the simple answer would be "because it creates time-domain aliasing". That's probably not a layman's term in your definition. But in order to understand what that means you need to work your way through the sampling theorem, basics of signals and systems, the DFT and specifically it's periodic properties, overlap-add/save, windowing and the effects thereof etc. Like it or not, signal processing is a math heavy discipline and without the proper background, you are not going to have much fun with ir

Look, I appreciate your interest and your effort, but I think you are better off  first taking a class on the subject so you get a hang on the fundamentals before you start writing code. Sure, you can watch some youtube videos to understand what a pilot does, but if you actually want to fly a plane yourself you need to go to pilot school.

@Hilmar, thanks for the advise. I understand but self-learning is currently only way for me by watching youtube and coursera audit, etc. I believe there are novice people who want to learn but the circumstances to not allow. Apologies if I disturbed you.

you are not disturbing at all . I'm just trying to help.  Self earning is perfectly fine here and there are very good free online resource that you can digest at your own  pace.  A good intro into digital filters is https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/.  Alan Oppenheim (who co-wrote the "bible" on digital signal processing) has a full course at https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/res-6-008-digital-signal-processing-spring-2011/pages/introduction/ All I'm suggesting is to spend a little more time with the math before hitting the keyboard.

@Hilmar, thanks for the references and advice. Will look into and build up math.

You left out the part of my previous answer which explains the issue in layman's terms.
Zeroing out a bin is the same as subtracting out a perfect sine wave of a specific bin centered frequency.  Most (or all) real world signals are imperfect.  If the signal you are trying to filter out is slightly different from an exactly perfect sinewave of that bin frequency, the subtraction will leave behind a lot of "junk".  Signals that are "between bins" are different from any (or any small subset of) basis vectors of an FFT, thus can't be removed by subtracting a basis vector, which are all perfect sine waves of bin centered frequencies, e.g. frequencies whose period is an exact integer sub-multiple of the FFT's length.  The subtraction will leave behind, often nasty, "junk".
If you convert the above into mathematical form, things such as matrices, "orthogonal transforms", "convolution", and "Sinc functions" might eventually appear, depending on the application domain and level of the math.
